# set checkbox in RecyclerView based on previously selected

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite, android-package-managers

I've been struggling with this for some time now and could not find a solution. Currently I'm population my `RecyclerView` with all the installed apps on the device using `PackageManager`. This works perfectly, here is the result I get:

[image: wworking]

The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to store/retrieve the selected checkbox, let me elaborate.

When I select a `Checkbox` I do the following inside `onBindViewHolder`:

```
holder.mAppSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.mAppSelect.setChecked(mDataSet.get(position).isSelected());
    holder.mAppSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mDataSet.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);

            if (holder.mAppSelect.isChecked()){
                //Ok great, I can use this to get the position, package name and app name that was selected/checked
            }else{
                //and it was un-sellected
            }
```

So, I can used the above to store the package name of the selected checkbox and also store a `boolean` of the state of the `checkbox` in `SQLite`, like this:

```
holder.mAppSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.mAppSelect.setChecked(mDataSet.get(position).isSelected());
    holder.mAppSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mDataSet.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);

            if (holder.mAppSelect.isChecked()){
                dbManager.insert(holder.mTextViewPackage.getText().toString(), true);
            }else{
                dbManager.insert(holder.mTextViewPackage.getText().toString(), false);
            }
```

This is where I have difficulty.. Lets say I close the `Activity` and open it again, I would like to get the packages/checkboxes that was selected from `SQLite` and set it again.

So, I'm looking for a way to "cycle" though each holder, get the package name from the holder so that I can check in `SQLite` if the checkbox was selected previously and set it accordingly.

---

I think it's also worth mentioning that applications may have been uninstalled or installed since the last time the application was launched. So that would mean that the `getAdapterPosition` will not remain the same.

---

EDIT 1:

This is how I populate the `Array` called `mDataSet`:

```
public class AppManager {
private Context mContext;
private AppInfo appInfo;
private ArrayList<AppInfo> myApps;

public AppManager(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
    myApps = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
}

public ArrayList<AppInfo> getApps() {
    loadApps();
    return myApps;
}

private void loadApps() {
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = mContext.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0);
    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        AppInfo newApp = new AppInfo();
        newApp.setAppName(getApplicationLabelByPackageName(packageInfo.packageName));
        newApp.setAppPackage(packageInfo.packageName);
        newApp.setAppIcon(getAppIconByPackageName(packageInfo.packageName));
        myApps.add(newApp);
    }

    Collections.sort(myApps, new Comparator<AppInfo>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(AppInfo s1, AppInfo s2) {
            return s1.getAppName().compareToIgnoreCase(s2.getAppName());

        }
    });

}


// Custom method to get application icon by package name
private Drawable getAppIconByPackageName(String packageName) {
    Drawable icon;
    try {
        icon = mContext.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Get a default icon
        icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }
    return icon;
}

// Custom method to get application label by package name
private String getApplicationLabelByPackageName(String packageName) {
    PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
    String label = "Unknown";
    try {
        applicationInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        if (applicationInfo != null) {
            label = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(applicationInfo);
        }

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return label;
}
}
```

Comment: how do you generate mDataSet values

Comment: @VinayakB it is the `Array` that is populate in the `RecyclerView` and i'm using `PackageManager` to populate the `Array`

Comment: Where do you check if it selected or not in  mDataSet Values with your sqlite values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is use shared preferences

when you start activity retrive state from shared preference like this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreference PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getAppContext());
for(i=0;i<mDataSet.size();i++)
{    
mDataSet.get(i).setSelected(sharedPreference.getBoolean(mDataSet.get(i).getAppPackage(),false));
}
```

and in your adapter save state like this.

```
holder.mAppSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
                    holder.mAppSelect.setChecked(mDataSet.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.mAppSelect.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                                    mDataSet.get(position).setSelected(isChecked);

           sharedPreference.edit().putBoolean(mDataSet.get(position).getAppPackage(), isChecked).commit();
           });
```

Comment: Ok, I have tested and it works. The only issue I have is that when I call the `SharedPreferences` from my `Activity` it returns null. But when I call it from my adapter inside `onBindViewHolder` or `onCreateViewHolder`, it keeps being called over and over again, as it would.. Is there a way to call it once inside my adapter?

Comment: it should not return null.if you are calling it from inside activity make sure you are passing right context... try doing this PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Comment: It's not null anymore, but I still have the issue of getting the selected checkboxe's package name because I don't have reference to the viewholder from my activity.

Comment: Never-mind, I can save the package names in SharedPreferences when I select a checkbox. Thanks, this will work perfectly,

Comment: i'm glade i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are following the right steps to show the checkbox selected, if isSelected() returns true, and to save the  state(checked/unckecked) of the checkbox in `SQLite`.

TO display the saved state of the checkboxes from `SQLite` when you close and open the `Activity` again, you just need to do is:

1. First, you need to get the latest list of installed packages.
2. Select data/checkbox values from `SQLite` where package name matches with the
   latest list of packages.
3. Now, as you have the saved checkbox values from SQLite, create data set 
   using the latest installed app list and the checkbox values which you 
   got from `SQLite`.
4. Pass it to your `RecyclerViewAdeptor`.

It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **OnClickListener** instead of *OnCheckedChangeListener*

Try this method,

1.Use a list which will have selected items. `//selectedlist`
If you want to store it permanantly, then use *SharedPref*.

2.Choose item's data which will be unique `//appname as string`

3.Set checked state based on the selected list item.

```
if(selectedlist.get(appname)!=null
            && (selectedlist.get(appname).equals("selected"))) {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }
```

4. Add listener to your checkbox,

```
    View.OnClickListener listener=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (selectedlist.get(appname)==null) {
                selectedlist.put(appname, "selected");
            else if (selectedlist.get(appname).equals("selected"))
                selectedlist.put(appname, "not selected");
            else 
                selectedlist.put(appname, "selected");
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(listener);
```